# Поменять css исходя из данных php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  background-color: #ddd;
  /* Grey background */
}

.skills {
  text-align: right;
  /* Right-align text */
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* Add some right padding */
  line-height: 40px;
  /* Set the line-height to center the text inside the 
    skill bar, and to expand the height of the container */
  color: white;
  /* White text color */
}

.html {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}


/* Green */
```

```html
<p>HTML</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="skills html">
    <?php echo $procentScoresHtml ?>%</div>
</div>
```

Нужно поменять width: 20% на width:`<?php echo $procentScoresHtml ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div class="skills html" style="width: <?php echo $procentScoresHtml ?>%;"><?php echo $procentScoresHtml ?>%</div>`

Comment: не, не работает так, к сожалению

Comment: а не все ок, спасибо)

Comment: @FlatronSamatron благодарить надо плюсиками за правильный ответ а не ок

Comment: я бы отблагодарил, но увы у меня репутация менее 15-ти баллов

Comment: @FlatronSamatron Тогда примите ответ как правильный, такая возможность должна быть у вас